# Flash player crashes in every browser

Tags: windows, google-chrome, firefox, browser, flash-player

I have searched the whole web to fix this issue but not a single solution worked for me. I was using windows7 I have never faced such issue that might be some issue with windows10. I not sure.

No videos plays in any browser and even some websites which using flash gives error as in screenshot.

Please help this out this issue is so annoying and disturbing.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you actually tried to uninstall flash through software and then install it again from the website? (or through third party software such as PatchMyPC or Ninite?)

Comment: update/uninstall/reinstall changed settings etc. but this is not helping. I didn't checked PatchMyPc i will check this out shortly.

Comment: I think it has something to do with my headphones i removed them restarted computer and now its working. Not sure what's the connection.